# What is the difference between a predicate nominative/predicate adjectives and a subject complement?

Tags: complements, predicate-adjectives, predicate-nominative

For example, the sentence "John was **a policeman**" or "Ben was **angry**." Both describe the subject, so I'd call them subject complements. But they could also be a predicate nominative and a predicate adjective.

Comment: [The Difference Between Predicate Nominative vs. Predicate Adjective.](https://www.thesaurus.com/e/grammar/predicate-nominative-vs-predicate-adjectives/#:~:text=Predicate%20Adjective-,The%20Difference%20Between%20Predicate%20Nominative,Predicate%20Adjective&text=A%20predicate%20nominative%20is%20a,the%20subject%20of%20a%20sentence.) ... *A predicate **nominative** is a **noun** that completes the linking verb in a sentence. Predicate **adjectives** complete the linking verb by **describing** the subject of a sentence.*

Comment: Predicate nominative/predicate adjective are alternative names for predicative complements, or PCs, which may have subject orientation or object orientation. In your examples, the PCs are said to be subjective, or to have subject orientation.

Comment: @BillJ Could you give an example where a PC has object orientation?

Comment: @linguisticturn In "They elected him **President**", the PC "President" has object orientation. And in "I consider Ed **untrustworthy**", the PC "untrustworthy" has object orientation. In the first example the PC is an NP; in the second an AdjP.

Comment: @BillJ Ah, I see. Thanks!